# ReactJS switch case only returns default when comparing strings

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement

I'm attempting to have a span display different content on the condition of a prop.

The prop `videoid` which is a simple youtube video id (like `Mn4oTaoyZKE`) renders absolutely fine. This is a result of completely skipping over the `case` statements and rendering the `default`.

I can't figure out the method for successfully checking if the videoid actually contains a string.

```
  switch(videoid){
    switch(videoid) {
      case videoid!="":
        return  <span className="text-muted small"><a href={this.props.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.props.title} {this.props.videoid}</a><VideoModal value={this.props.videoid}/></span>

      case videoid=="":
        return  <span className="text-muted small"><a href={this.props.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.props.title} {this.props.videoid}</a></span>

      default:
        return videoid;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's just not how `switch` works. `videoid` is neither `true` nor `false`, which are the two cases you have, hence it always hits the `default`.

Comment: Ok, that clarified it. I added the answer below. Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to add a separate function which made the check

```
class Title extends Component {

  isValidId(videoid){
    if (videoid != "")
      return true
    else if (videoid == "")
      return false

  }

  switch(videoid){

    switch(this.isValidId(videoid)) {
      case true:
        return  <span className="text-muted small"><a href={this.props.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.props.title} {this.props.videoid}</a><VideoModal value={this.props.videoid}/></span>

      case false:
        return  <span className="text-muted small"><a href={this.props.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.props.title} {this.props.videoid}</a></span>

      default:
        return videoid;
    }
  }

render(){
    return (
      //<span className="text-muted small"><a href={this.props.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.props.title} {this.props.videoid}</a><VideoModal value={this.props.videoid}/></span>
      this.switch(this.props.videoid)

    );
  }

}

export default Title;
```

Comment: What's the point of a switch here? The default is unreachable. Just do `if`/`else` or a ternary conditional expression. For that matter, isVideoId is implemented in a way that implies it could fall through to return undefined, while is unlikely; why not just `return videoId != ""`?